# In latex to HTML converters like latex2wp what is the alternative to eqnarray or align

Tags: html

Though my primary problem has been [solved](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18511/i-used-eqnarray-ignorantly-and-now-muct-change-all-to-align-any-solutions), I am trying to put my document on my group's blog. I use [Luca Trevisan's latex2wp](http://lucatrevisan.wordpress.com/latex-to-wordpress/) but it does not render either of the two. Reason, if I correctly read on [wordpress' blog](http://en.support.wordpress.com/latex/) is that

> One thing to keep in mind is that WordPress puts all of your \LaTeX code inside a \LaTeX math environment. If you try to use \LaTeX that doesn’t work inside the math environment (such as \begin{align} ... \end{align}), you will get an error

So is there any way around it anyone here knows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea if this will work with the latex2wp converter (being a fan of MathML myself), but the way to get the equivalent of `align` but *within* a mathematical environment is to use the `aligned` environment.  From the AMSMath manual on p5:

```
\begin{equation*}
\left.\begin{aligned}
B' &= -\partial\times E,\\
E' &= \partial\times B - 4\pi j,
\end{aligned}
\right\}
\qquad \text{Maxwell's equations}
\end{equation*}
```

produces

[image: Maxwell's equations]

Comment: I have used the Mathjax plugin for blogspot, but the rendering is nowehre close to say the rendering at StackExchange websites. For wordpress, I could not find any, do they have a mathml alternative? (Ill try to use this and see what I get. Thanks for answering +1)

Comment: @yayu: That's odd that you find a different between MathJaX and SE since SE uses MathJaX.  May be worth asking what their settings are.  Anyway, for Wordpress, if you use their hosting then there's no MathML plugin but if you host it yourself then you might just be in luck as I wrote one a while back (more as a proof-of-concept).  Take a look at: http://www.math.ntnu.no/~stacey/Vanilla/WPMathML/ (it needs a couple of modifications to the WP code - just to clean up their XHTML - which is why it can't run on the WP hosts)